# How to read variable's value in Excel spreadsheet using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

NoI have an SSIS package that transfer and archive files every 4 hours. Inside of that package I have execute SQL Task that execute stored procedure in which I'm calling one column from Archive table. My stored procedure works and every time I run the project with breakpoints I can see that a variable is getting the column's value. 
The next step I need to do is to transfer that value into Excel Spreadsheet. For that I created Data Flow Task with Excel Source, Derived Column and Excel Destination. Excel Source File is just a temporary file with no data in it, so in Derived Column task I'm replacing 'F1' column with user variable and in Destination File I'm mapping that value with the right column. 
Every time I run the package I get a successful run, but my Destination File is empty. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I tried every possible option but it doesn't work. 
[image: Control Flow]

[[image: Data Flow Task-Derived Column Task]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for @Hadi's answer:

Using Script Component Source.

1. Add your variable to the read variables
2. Add your output Column Name to Output0 output.
3. Add the following code to create your data to process

   ```
   Output0Buffer.AddRow();
   Output0Buffer.[Your Column Name] = Variables.[Your Variable name];
   ```

And you are done!!!

Comment: Well done. Now the OP has a nice and complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you said

> Excel Source File is just a temporary file with no data in it.

The data flow task is used to transfer data from a source to a destination. If the source is empty then no rows are transfered.

You should replace Excel source and derived column with a script component that generates rows based on the variable that stores the value you need.